# Install only clang and clang++ in llvm - windows

Tags: c++, windows, installation, clang, clang++

I'm new to clang in windows and I want to only install clang and clang++ executables.

Since the full installation of llvm and clang requires more than 1GB.

Can anyone tell me how to install only clang or which executables, files, or dlls to exclude in the installation?

Comment: Can you specify the reason you want a minimum installation? Based on Clang's documentation, it requires LLVM to work. Just the binaries for LLVM and clang together is already ~700mb for 64bit windows.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep My hard drive is almost full, leaving about 13% free space.

Comment: [Minimal LLVM build with C API](https://boxbase.org/entries/2018/jun/11/minimal-llvm-build/) There's a link about how to build it for C only, which might be relevant. However, I would suggest to investigate in a new hard drive, even a flash drive if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you install LLVM from sources, you can configure build targets using some flags, as explained [here](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-the-source-code-and-building-llvm).

Probably are looking for a build like (make sure you have CMake installed and in your PATH):

```
git clone --config core.autocrlf=false https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel [...]
```

Thus you only include `clang` project being the build type the minimum.